# How to show exponential integral is finite

Tags: integration

I have an integral of the form

$$ t \int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{x^2}$$

$t$ here can take both positive and negative values.

How can I proceed to show that this integral exists (or not) and is finite (or not) in both the cases ($t>0,t\le0$).

Comment: Are you supposed to know about exponential integrals or incomplete gamma function ?

Comment: No, would that help?

Comment: If you are not supposed to know, just forget. When you will know these, you will see that the problem is quite simple. What kobe answered is simple and nice. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t  \le 0$, convergence of the integral follows from

$$0 \le \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{tx}}{x^2}\, dx \le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx = 1.$$

If $t > 0$, divergence of the integral follows from the fact that

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{tx}}{x^2}\, dx > \int_1^\infty \frac{tx}{x^2}\, dx = t\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\, dx = \infty.$$

Comment: is there a specific name this proof mechanism goes by? Would help my future causes.

Comment: The main idea is to use the direct comparison test for improper integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Just see this. If $t<0$ we have

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{x^2}dx < \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx < \infty. $$